# Python Unicode Error Reading an Arabic PDF into txt

Tags: python, pdf, unicode

**Goal**

To convert a PDF file that has some arabic text within it into a utf-8 txt file in Python using PyPDF.

**Code**

What I have tried:

```
import pyPdf
import codecs
input_filepath = "hans_wehr_searchable_pdf.pdf"#pdf file path
output_filepath = "output.txt"#output text file path
output_file = open(output_filepath, "wb")#open output file
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(input_filepath, "rb"))#read PDF
for page in pdf.pages:#loop through pages
    page_text = page.extractText()#get text from page
    page_text = page_text.decode(encoding='utf-8')#decode 
    output_file.write(page_text)#write to file
output_file.close()#close
```

**Error**

I however receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf2txt.py", line 9, in <module>
    page_text = page_text.decode(encoding='windows-1256')#decode 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1256.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: How about you extract just the code and data causing the issue and build the usual minimal but complete example with them? Consider for example whether it's relevant that the data came from a PDF or not. Also, consider upgrading to a recent Python version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of opening the file using the built in python `open` you could try to open the file using `codecs` and specifying the encoding of the file when opening, which it looks like you already imported `codecs`. Your code would change to:

```
import pyPdf
import codecs
input_filepath = "hans_wehr_searchable_pdf.pdf"#pdf file path
output_filepath = "output.txt"#output text file path
output_file = open(output_filepath, "wb")#open output file
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(codecs.open(input_filepath, "rb", encoding='utf-8'))#read PDF
for page in pdf.pages:#loop through pages
    page_text = page.extractText()#get text from page
    page_text = page_text.decode(encoding='utf-8')#decode 
    output_file.write(page_text)#write to file
output_file.close()#close
```